# Missing Swift files

Tags: swift, xcode

I don't really understand what's hapening but I'm not able to see all my Swift files on Xcode project navigator, but when I open my project directory I see them all, it looks like reference problems.

I'm receiving some invalid redeclaration problems.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing in the search field in bottom regarding missing your file ?

Comment: Also the error which you are getting, you have already declared a struct with name itemm in your project and here your are redeclaring it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the one of the xcode-beta builds? They seem to have some problems with file handling every now and then. Restarting fixes it for me most of the times.